# Android using Dependency Injection on Fragments

Tags: android, dependency-injection

I can use Dependency Injection for `Realm` successful, i can use `@Inject` into activity without any problem, now i want to use that and inject that into Fragments, since i novice to use this method, i can't do that

`ApplicationModule` class:

```
@Module
public class ApplicationModule {

    @Provides
    Context provideApplicationContext() {
        return AlachiqApplication.getInstance();
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    RealmConfiguration provideRealmConfiguration() {
        final RealmConfiguration.Builder builder = new RealmConfiguration.Builder()
                .schemaVersion(Migration.SCHEMA_VERSION)
                .deleteRealmIfMigrationNeeded()
                .migration(new Migration());
        return builder.build();
    }

    @Provides
    Realm provideDefaultRealm(RealmConfiguration config) {
        return Realm.getInstance(config);
    }
}
```

`ApplicationComponent` class:

```
@Component(modules = ApplicationModule.class)
@Singleton
public interface ApplicationComponent {
    void inject(ActivityRegister target);
    void inject(ActivityMain target);
    void inject(FragmentEbooks target);
    void inject(FragmentDocuments target);
    void inject(SocketServiceProvider target);
}
```

how can i edit or create other class component and module to inject realm into that? by the way, i have more fragment on my application

Thanks in advance

Comment: Don't you actually just need to add `void inject (MyFragment fragment)` into `ApplicationComponent`?

Comment: @EpicPandaForce i test it sir, but after that i can't inject that, if i define that on `ApplicationComponent` how can i inject?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add another target method in your component like,

```
@Component(modules = ApplicationModule.class)
@Singleton
public interface ApplicationComponent {
  void inject(ActivityRegister target);
  void inject(ActivityMain target);
  void inject(SocketServiceProvider target);
  void inject(MyFragment target);
}
```

And in your fragment do similar thing what your doing in your activity.

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment{
   @inject Realm realm;

   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ((MyApplication) getActivity().getApplication()).getComponent().inject(this);
}
```