# what is the correct was to inject dependency in fragments

Tags: android, dagger-2, dagger

i wanted to inject dependency in my fragments how can i do this with dagger.
i'm trying to get the activityComponent object from the MainActivity class.
But if i have multiple classes using the same fragment do i need to type cast by checking the instance.Is there any simple way...

```
public class RepositoryFragment extends Fragment implements 
               RepositoryContract.View {
        @Inject
        RepositoryContract.Presenter presenter;

        @Nullable
        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

            View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_repository, container, false);

            // obtain Dagger 2 ActivityComponent from Actiity
            ActivityComponent activityComponent = ((MainActivity)getActivity()).getActivityComponent();
            // Inject dependencies
            activityComponent.inject(this);

            presenter.setView(this);
            ...
            return view;
        }
    }
```

Comment: follow this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32113953/dagger-2-on-android-inject-same-dependency-in-activity-and-retained-fragment

Comment: _But if i have multiple classes using the same fragment do i need to type cast_ You can always have your Activities implement an interface

Comment: this problem is solved by  having a hash map which will contain <ActivityName, ActivityComponent> whenever we try to get the component we can search in the hash map if it is present it will return it for as many fragments we need.